# Code testing for beginners - how to do?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

Lets say that I have a lot of nested loops (3-4 levels) in a java method and each of these loops can have some if-else blocks. How can I check if all these things are working properly ? I am looking for a logical way to test this instead of using a brute force approach like substituting illegal values.

EDIT:
Can you also suggest some good testing books for beginners ?

Comment: What sort of testing? Functional testing? Coverage testing? White box? Black box?

Comment: It's not "brute force" - it is a normal flow. You manually compose different valid inputs, different valid and invalid edge-cases, and different invalid inputs and check if you get what you expect

Comment: @GregHewgill - I am new to development and not yet familiar with all the testing jargon. I am looking for something "basic" for now. Btw, can you suggest how I may begin learning the basics of testing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I've always been taught basic testing is to handle around edge cases as much as possible.

For example, if you are checking the condition that variable i is between 0 and 10 `if(i>0 &&i<10)`, what I would naturally test is a few values that make the test condition true, preferably near the edges, then a few on the edges that are a combination of true and false, and finally cases that are way out of bounds. With the aforementioned condition, I'd test 1,5 ,9, 0, 10, -1, 11, then finally an extremely large integer, both positive and negative.

This sort of goes against the "not substituting illegal values)", but I feel that you have to do that in order to ensure that your conditions fail properly.

Answer (score 1):

[EMMA](http://emma.sourceforge.net/userguide_single/userguide.html) is a code coverage tool.  You run your unittests under EMMA and it will produce an HTML report with colorized source code showing which lines were reached and which were not.  Based on that you can add tests to make sure you're testing all the various branches.

Each if/then in your code contains a boolean sub-expression as is the sub-expression used in a loop to decide whether to enter/rerun the loop.  Predicate coverage should tell give you a good idea how thorough your tests are.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) explains predicate coverage

> Condition coverage (or predicate coverage) - Has each boolean sub-expression evaluated both to true and false? This does not necessarily imply decision coverage.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that using debug is easiest way to find the mistake. You can find a full explanation about debug at this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/.

Also you can use this link: http://webster.cs.washington.edu:8080/practiceit/ for practising.

Answer (score 0):

for example find input which will go through each of those loops with some values. then find input which will go through each branch of the if's. Then find input which will go through the loops with large or small or illegal values.

Answer (score 0):

Set some input and output data. Make the calculations yourself. 
Create a class to check if the output values match the ones you separately calculated.

Example:

input: Array(3,4,5,6);

output (sum of odd numbers) : 8

```
 class TestClass{

     //test case
     //here you keep changing the array (extreme values, null etc..
    public void test1(){
     int[] anArray=new int[4];
        anArray[0] = 3;
        anArray[1] = 4;
        anArray[2] = 5;
        anArray[3] = 6;
       int s=Calculator.oddSum(x);
       if (s==8) 
            System.out.println("Passed");
       else 
            System.out.println("Failed");
    }

    public static void main(){ 
      TestClass t=new TestClass();
      t.test1();    
    }
}
```